# Laravel MySQL Cannot insert null in nullable foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

I'm going crazy with this error/bug. I'm using Laravel 4.2 to develop an application in which I have a table created like this:

```
Schema::create('stock_items', function(Blueprint $table){
  ....
  $table->integer('color_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
  $table->integer('size_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
  ....
  $table->foreign('color_id')->references('id')->on('colors');
  $table->foreign('size_id')->references('id')->on('sizes');
});
```

Both columns can be `null` but when I insert something like this:

```
$stock_item->color_id = NULL;
$stock_item->size_id = NULL;
```

I get a MySQL Error telling me: `Could not insert: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails`

BUT if I run the exact same query laravel logs in any MySQL client, the row gets inserted. So, what's going on??

Answer (score 0):

If everything is ok using mySQL client you should see what's the difference between your SQL statement and the Laravel's.

```
$queries = DB::getQueryLog();
$last_query = end($queries);
```

checks what Laravel executed.

Comment: The query is not added to the query log. I suppose because it fails. But it sends this message: ```(SQL: insert into `model_items_stock` (`model_item_id`, `color_option_id`, `size_option_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1, NULL, NULL, 2015-06-11 21:03:23, 2015-06-11 21:03:23))```
Which I run and works.

Comment: Did you isolate your code? Maybe there's another problematic query after this query.

Comment: That's not the case, as a matter of fact, that's the only query the function runs.